# Pasting multi-line code block sometimes fragments the code

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, code

I was trying to answer a SO question that involved some VBA. The question had a code block, which I copied to my VBA editor (which resulted in some non-indented lines, made some fixes, then put it back on my clipboard.

In the SO answer textbox, I wrote a brief answer, and then clicked the code-block button, and pasted at the insertion point. SO honored the first few lines, but then the non-indented code terminated the code block, and the remainder was treated as normal text/paragraph. Took me a while to realise I needed to add 4 spaces to each of the text/paragraph lines in order to correct it.

Is this something that could/should be handled by JavaScript, when I paste at a code-block inserion point? Or should I just do the indentation in my editor *before* putting it on the clipboard?

Comment: You should paste it in first, then select the whole thing and format it as code. That will correctly indent everything.

Comment: Will give it a try later.

Comment: Also, pre-indenting in your text editor with 4 spaces also works, like you mentioned.

Comment: Paste the whole code. Select All and click {} option.
see this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207842/how-to-easily-indent-multi-line-code